# Transfer of parameters between JSP and servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, web

I am developing a servlet and jsp application with the front end mostly coded in `html/css/javascript`.

Now i have called a servlet from `login jsp`, to validate the user name and password and redirect to `dashboard.jsp`. This is happening successfully. I realized that, to pass parameters of username with ease during post, we need to use, `getRequestDispatcher` rather than `sendRedirect`.

I have the following questions.

1. Now in dashboard.jsp, through tabs i navigate to various other jsps.
   I need the username passed from the servlet in all of the jsps. Can
   we define something as a global variable and access it across all
   jsp pages?
2. Is the approach of having the front-end mostly with
   html/css/javascript inside jsp an efficient one?

Please pour your views and expertise and oblige!!

Comment: use `session` attribute to pass values globally.See the link in answer

Answer (score 1):

You could set all the values into the response object before forwarding the request to the jsp Or you can put your values into a session bean and access it in the jsp.

You can pass information to and fro between `servlets` and `jsp` using `sessions` and `servlet context` information.

For more detail information see **[Sharing values between Servlets and Jsp](http://getch.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/sharing-values-between-servlets-and-jsp/)**

Answer (score 0):

The data is on the server. The only thing you need to know is the identifier of the user making the current request. That's what the HTTP session is for. When the user has successfully authenticates, add his unique ID to the session:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("authenticatedUserId", user.getId());
```

Then in all subsequent requests, you can get the ID of the authenticated user from the session, and get the information about this user from the database:

```
Long authenticatedUserId = request.getSession().getAttribute(("authenticatedUserId");
User user = userService.findById(authenticatedUserId);
// store the user in the request to make it available to the view
request.setAttribute("user, user);
```

Note that after login, you should definitely redirect to the dashboard servlet, and not forward to it: you really don't want the user to refresh the dashboard and re-post the authentication form.